# Is the polynomial ring over a discrete valuation ring local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring. Is the polynomial ring $R[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ a local ring?

Comment: Of course not (this would imply that $k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ is a local ring, where $k$ is the residue field of $R$, but this ring has infinitely many maximal ideals (Euclid), at least when $n>0$).

Answer (score 11):

A polynomial ring $A[X]$ is never a local ring!

Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$. Then $A[X]/\mathfrak mA[X]\simeq (A/\mathfrak m)[X]$, so it is a polynomial ring over a field. But the polynomial rings over fields contain infinitely many irreducible polynomials (which generate infinitely many maximal ideals), so there are infinitely many maximal ideals in $A[X]$ containing $\mathfrak mA[X]$.

Comment: Do the case $A=0$ first.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I leave it to you!